# Better way to Read /Write Memory<byte> to/from POCO

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core

I am communicating with a machine that sends/received structured binary data to my netcore service. The machine supplier's new library uses Memory in their library's API.

I have written the following code for Ser/Des which works, but seems verbose. I know I can wrap some of this in methods/helpers, but it feels cumbersome compared to the "old" Streams & BinaryWriter/BinaryReader approach.

***Is there a better way to approach this? A better part of the framework or technique I should be using?***

#### Deserialising from Memory:

```csharp
public void Read(Memory<byte> data)
    {
      if (data.Length < StaticSize) // StaticSize = 56. Defined by machine's struct.
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Span length too small. Minimum: {StaticSize}, Received: {data.Length}.");

      var s = data.Span;
      MemoryMarshal.TryRead<bool>(s.Slice(0, 1), out _forward);
      MemoryMarshal.TryRead<bool>(s.Slice(1, 2), out _reverse);
      SomeString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s.Slice(2, 22)).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
      Dynamics = new TcDynamics(data.Slice(24)); // "TcDynamics" object de-serialized in same manner as this.
    }
```

#### Serialising to Memory:

```csharp
 public void Write(Memory<byte> data)
    {
      if (data.Length < StaticSize) // StaticSize = 56. Defined by machine's struct.
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Span length too small. Minimum: {StaticSize}, Received: {data.Length}.");

      var s = data.Span;
      MemoryMarshal.TryWrite<bool>(s.Slice(0, 1), ref _forward);
      MemoryMarshal.TryWrite<bool>(s.Slice(1, 2), ref _reverse);
      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_someString).CopyTo(s.Slice(2,22)); // Strings are fixed length (21 + termination).
      Dynamics.Write(data.Slice(24)); // "TcDynamics" object serialized in same manner as this.
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think it is cumbersome? Have you considered `SequenceReader` and `PipeWriter` [1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines)

Comment: @PeterCsala, when using a binary reader, I could just call something like: `myDouble= reader.ReadDouble();` or `writer.Write(myDouble);` `writer.Write(myString, lengthInBytes);` I know I can create that myself using Facade pattern to hide away most of the above, but thought there would be a better way somewhere else. I will have a look at your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I agree that those abstractions make the usage more convenient. `Memory`, `Span` and `ReadOnlySpan`were designed to work mainly with `byte`and `char` types.

Comment: If the data structure in `data` is the same, couldn't you then load a `MemoryStream` with the data, and then use a `BinaryReader-/Writer as you did before?

Comment: @HenrikHansen, I couldn't figure out how to do this without copying data into the Memory Stream. That feels like I'm losing one of the efficiency benefits of Memory<T>. I.e. I'd be creating memory in the stream to copy the memory<> into. Then the read operation would be copying to variable. The last copy is unavoidable, but the interim one I was hoping to avoid with these new classes. have I misunderstood the MemoryStream WriteAsync docs?